# How to solve Node:SCSS Problem? Any Solutions

Tags: node-sass

**If you had solve this type of issue then give some solutions..**
=> changed: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\NA-TOURS\sass\main.scss

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/NA-TOURS/sass/abstracts/_variables.scss",
  "line": 26,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "Invalid CSS after \"$default-font-size\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \": 1.6rem;\"",
  "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"$default-font-size\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \": 1.6rem;\"\n        on line 26 of sass/abstracts/_variables.scss\n        from line 3 of sass/main.scss\n>> $default-font-size: 1.6rem;\r\n   ^\n"
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question ?

Comment: did you please, tell me what does this message show us only, I didn't understand clearly?